# Facing issue while git checkout in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am getting below error while performing checkout in Jenkins on Bitbucket. It was working fine earlier, but is now giving errors. Nothing has been changed configuration wise.

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "checkout" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
     Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [bitbucketCreds_PSW, bitbucketCreds]
     See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
The recommended git tool is: NONE
Warning: CredentialId "****" could not be found.
> git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir 
E:\Jenkins\workspace\Deployment_Pipelines\ODI_INC_Deployment_Pipeline@2\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://xyz/abc.git # timeout=10
Using shallow fetch with depth 1
Fetching upstream changes from https://xyz/abc.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.27.0.windows.1'
> git fetch --no-tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- https://xyz/abc.git 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://xyz/abc.git
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1003)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1244)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1308)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
at 
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- https://xyz/abc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://xyz/abc.git': Failed to connect to xyz port 443: Timed out
```

Jenkins stage steps :

```
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
  branches: [[name: '*/master']],
  doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
  extensions: [
   [$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, honorRefspec: true, noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: 
    true],
   [$class: 'SparseCheckoutPaths',  sparseCheckoutPaths: [[path: 'PQR/Deploy'], [path: 
   'Pipelines/Deploy']]]
    ],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [
    [name: 'origin', credentialsId: 'SB_Jira', url: 'https://xyz/abc.git']
    ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after adding proxy details in git config.